# Java: for loop crashing using string charAt method

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have a bug in this block of code. The debugger suggest it´s cause is this line of code `char chr = getSecretWord.charAt(i);`

What this code does is look for a match between `userInput` and `secretWord`. I have the `for loop` to go through the length of the secretWord letters one by one, and if there is a letter matching  return true. If not, return false... but the program crashes when it is suppose to just return false... I guess it is something with this line, but do not know exactly what `getSecretWord.charAt(i);`

```
    private boolean isMatchingSecretWord(String userInput)
{
    String secretWord = "";
    String getSecretWord = getSecretWord();
    for (int i = 0; i <= getSecretWord.length();i++)
        {
        char chr = getSecretWord.charAt(i);
        secretWord = ""+chr;

        if (secretWord.equals(userInput))
        {
            println("is true");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As an side note, is what I´ve done with this code correct, assigning the getSecretWorld() Method to a String so I can use the Strings method `length()`?

`String getSecretWord = getSecretWord();`

`for (int i = 0; i <= getSecretWord.length();i++)`

**Debug code:**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4    
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)    
    at Hangman.isMatchingSecretWord(Hangman.java:49)    
    at Hangman.userInput(Hangman.java:34)    
    at Hangman.run(Hangman.java:20)*
```

Comment: @Kalecser has your solution. Next time you ask a similar question, please show us the error. You make it unnecessarily tough on us by making us guess.

Comment: `getSecretWord.charAt(getSecretWord.length())` should give you a nice `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= getSecretWord.length(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getSecretWord.length(); i++)
//               ^^^
//             see here
```

The valid indexes for an `n`-character string (or an `n`-element array) are `0` through `n-1` inclusive.

So, if your secret word is `xyyzy`, the valid indexes are zero through four. Your original loop iterates with `i` set to zero through *five,* hence the problem.

---

But there seems to be a lot of unnecessary code in there, when you could get away with something simple.

First, I would remove a source of confusion - the function name sounds like the user input and the secret word have to match completely whereas your comment indicates otherwise:

> Thanks, this works. But the reason for the loops is that the user enters one letter, I want to see if that letter is within the SecretWord. (it´s a hangman game).

In that case, you simply want to see if the single character exists in the secret word. I would change the function name to suit and, even then, it can be done with a lot less code:

```
private boolean isInSecretWord (String userInput) {
    String secretWord = getSecretWord();
    return secretWord.contains(userInput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But the reason for the loops is that the user enters one letter, I want to see if that letter is within the SecretWord. (it´s a hangman game).

Comment: @Tom, that makes a little more sense as to why you're accessing individual characters. However, you can still do that in a much more succinct way - see the update.

Comment: @paxdiablo.. any reason that method does not show up in the java documentation of strings? I find the java documentation a bit messy, or maybe it´s just me that isn´t used to it.

Comment: Not sure which doco you're looking at, @Tom, but it's been in Java for a while - have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and search for `boolean contains`.

Answer (score 1):

You were getting out of bounds error as your for loop wasn't looping correctly, I have modified it so that the loop doesn't go out of bounds and also your secretWord variable wasn't populating correctly, the code should now work as intended :)

```
private boolean isMatchingSecretWord(String userInput)
{
    String secretWord = "";
    String getSecretWord = getSecretWord();
    for (int i = 0; i < getSecretWord.length();i++)
        {
        char chr = getSecretWord.charAt(i);
        secretWord = secretWord + chr;

        if (secretWord.equals(userInput))
        {
            println("is true");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```